# Where can I find a good collection of pre-generated characters for D&D 4th Edition?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation

I'm looking for sources of pre-generated characters for D&D 4th Edition. I'm looking for all sorts of levels, in addition to the typical level 1 pre-gens. The purpose of this is for running short adventures at various levels and giving players quick options for character generation.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Unfortunately resource recommendation questions typically make poor stack exchange questions. I've voted to close this question for that reason. However, I do hope that you will stick around. Have a look at our [FAQ] or check out meta if you have any questions. Again welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found mostly what I was looking for at this website:

http://dungeonsmaster.com/pre-generated-character-library/

The pre-generated characters here appear to be meant for D&D Encounters and are mostly 1st level, but could be adapted for other adventures.